# Realm Swift Sort By If Object Exists

Tags: swift, realm

Given the following example code...

```
class Example: Object {
     dynamic var other: OtherObj? // Some other object type
}

let realm = Realm()
let result = realm.object(Example.self).sorted( ??? )
```

How would one perform a sort so that all `Example` objects with `other` as nil are sorted before all other objects with `other` as not nil and still have the result be of type `Results<Example>`?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek I Disagree. I am looking for an answer that returns a type of `Results<Example>` that question's answer returns an array.

Comment: But shouldn't this just work like any sort then? Swift2: `...sorted("other")`, Swift3: `...sorted(byKeyPath: "other")`?

Comment: @AnthonyDito as it was stated in the answer for the duplicate, there is no way to custom sort `Results`, `Realm` just doesn't support that at the moment